# Programatically chaniging the height of containers in a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, uistackview

I have two views in a vertical stack view. I am trying to make a bar chart - the bottom view is the bar and the top view is transparent. I needed to make it so that for each bar on the chart, these two views change size so that the correct bar can be shown.

I have the following constraint in the code to try and achieve this:

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topBars[0], attribute: 
NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: 
NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: bottomBars[0], attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, multiplier: 2, constant: 0)
view.addConstraints([heightConstraint])
```

My vertical stack view is set to fill proportionally.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What went wrong ? is the constraint not applied ?

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

> I would recommend using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) instead of reinventing the wheel

**Secondly**

> And if your are interested, you can see in detail how they solved this very problem as to me a stack view doesn't seem a good option

But if you are using `UIStackView`

You can hide the view in the `UIStackView` and it is automatically hidden.

```
view.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to set vertical stack view is set to fill and then normally set height in multiplier form with respect to view (here 2nd view's height is set respect to 1st view .
and You can hide the view inside the UIStackView and it is automatically hidden

```
view.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you